# Prove that the convergence is not uniform

Tags: real-analysis, convergence-divergence

> Define $$f_n(x)=\frac{1-|x|^n}{1+|x|^n}$$ Prove that the convergence is not uniform.

---

We have $\lim\limits_{n\rightarrow\infty}f_n(x)=\begin{cases}1\; &|x|<1\\0\; &|x|=1\\-1\; &|x|>1\end{cases}\Longrightarrow f(x)=\begin{cases}1\; &|x|<1\\0\; &|x|=1\\-1\; &|x|>1\end{cases}$

To prove $f_n$ does not converges uniformly to $f$, we use contradiction. 
Pick $\epsilon=\frac{1}{4}$. For any $N$, note that $f_N$ is continuous. Hence, pick $x > 1$ close to $1$ so that $|f_N (x)| <\frac{1}{4}$. But  $|f(x) − f_N (x)| \geq\frac{3}{4} >\epsilon $ which is a contradiction, so the convergence is not uniform.

---

I am looking for different ways to do this problem. Can we do it without using $\epsilon$?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If each $f_n$ is continuous and $f_n\to f$ uniformly, then $f$ is continuous. Since the limit function is not continuous in this case, the convergence must not be uniform.

Comment: Or the $f_n$s are discontinuous. You can have a series of nowhere continuous functions which converge uniformly to a nowhere continuous function, for example.

Comment: The given functions are continuous.

Comment: What theorem are you using?

Comment: My mistake. Might still be a useful thing to note for the OP.

Comment: @ Simple: The first sentence of my answer is the theorem I'm using. I don't think it has a special name. It can be proved using the triangle inequality.

Comment: @carmichael561  ["Uniform limit theorem"?](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Uniform_limit_theorem)

Comment: @ Clement: Sure.